# What is the difference between 抗拒 and 抵御?

Tags: word-choice, word

These two words seem to be the same for me. Both mean "resist".

According to 百度词典:

- 抗拒：抵抗并拒绝
- 抵御：抵挡;抗御

At least 抵抗 and 反抗 seems to be different in that it is used to counter "attack".

- 抵抗：用力量制止对方的进攻、抗击外来的武装侵略或敌军进攻

So regarding 抗拒 and 抵御, how can I use them apart?

Comment: title asks for 抵抗 and 抵御，text（last line) for 抗拒 and 抵御!
bkrs： **抗拒**  resist; oppose; defy; withstand:
抗拒搜查 resistance to search
抗拒法律 offer resistance to the law
他再也抗拒不住她的魅力。 He could resist her charm no longer.
搞创造对他有无法抗拒的吸引力。 Creative work appealed to him irresistibly.#7535

resist; defy
他无法抗拒诱惑。 He can't resist temptation.
**抵御** （抵抗） resist; withstand:
抵御进攻 resist an attack
抵御外侮 resist foreign aggression #9401，examples seem to indicate that 抗拒 is the more general term, whereas 
抵御 involves resistance to attack, iciba examples: 竖起衣领抵御冷雾,防火墙抵御黑客袭击,抵御疾病

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**抗拒**：1. 抵抗, resist; 2. 拒绝, refuse;

**抵御**：1. 抵挡, 抵抗, resist; 2. 抵御, 预防, protect from;

So, there is an overlap in meaning (sense 1) between these two words. For example, 无法抗拒==无法抵御; 抗拒诱惑==抵御诱惑;

Also, there is a different usage(sense 2) between the two. For example,  抗拒搜查 means you fight against police in order to resist their searching in your home;well,  抵御搜查 would mean that you hide your evidence to **protect** it to be found out by police; another example is 抵御疾病 means you could wear more to protect you from the disease like a cold; well, there is no direct way that you can fight with diseases, so 抗拒疾病 seems not to make any sense. You can't literally **refuse** the diseases when they come.

Comment: Thanks and yes I found 诱惑 is used in both cases on Pleco, so I was confused. Seems that 抗拒 is more initiative and/or agressive while 抵御 sounds more passive.

Comment: @Blaszard yeah, that kinda idea.

Answer (score 2):

> 抗 = resist; 拒 = repel
>
> 抗拒 is 'actively resist and repel'

~

> 抵 = brace ; 禦 = keep out; defend; guard against; take precautions against
>
> 抵禦 is 'actively resist plus passively defend'

We have terms like 力抗 (forcefully resist), 力拒 (forcefully repel); but we don't have 力禦 (forcefully prevent/ defend)

- 抵禦 something you can actively resist and passively defend against , like 寒冷，疾病 and 外敵
- 抗拒 something you can actively resist and repel, coincidentally, 寒冷，疾病 and 外敵 all qualify for that